# COUNTIFS formula assistance

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the countifs formula to count products with a specific product number and in a state of available.
When I type the formula it looks like:

```
=COUNTIFS('APS22'!M:Q,210-000742-005,'APS22'!M:Q,"AVAILABLE")
```

but when I click on the cell to view the formula, it changes the product number:

```
=COUNTIFS('APS22'!M:Q,210-742-5,'APS22'!M:Q,"AVAILABLE")
```

M is the column that references the product number. Q is the state.

At first I thought that the product number in the range I am referencing has zero available, hence the 0, so I checked the product on the sheet referenced and there are plenty of that product number with a status of available. The count is always 0. If the formula worked.. it should show 20.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to put your product number in quotes and then it won't be subject to XL "helpfully" removing the leading zeros.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Though it is still not working. The count is still 0 :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep it in quotes so it doesn't format it as Date or something else

try this

```
=COUNTIFS('APS22'!M:Q,"210-000742-005",'APS22'!M:Q,"AVAILABLE")
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Though it is still not working. The count is still 0 :(

Comment: @NewNow2356 can you show how the sheet looks?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My range was incorrect! Thank you, everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Excel spreadsheet syntax taken from [MS Office Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

Empirically it **can** be made to work but you have to obey additional unstated criteria. If you do either string search on its own then you will get the appropriate count of correct matches. Combining them has gotchas!

```
=COUNTIFS('APS22'!M:M,"210-000742-005",'APS22'!Q:Q,"AVAILABLE")
```

Or whichever column contains "AVAILABLE" should work. I chose Q:Q arbitrarily.

But if you try to do it with overlapping regions even though they obviously do meet the stated criterion of "being the same size" it returns 0 for no good reason that I can see.

I think you have been unlucky this second failure is due to a bug in Excel.